# Accessing the underlying network withn a VPN

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I'm using a computer which connects to my companies network via a VPN. When I try to access my local network it is unreachable as long as the VPN is active. Normally this is of course the desired behaviour, but sometimes I need to access my private server as well.
Is there some way how I can do this without disconnecting from VPN, accessing my network and then reconnect to VPN? After all, the network is still be there because is is used for the VPN as well.

I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise here.

Comment: Ask your network admin about split tunneling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you setup VPN using the build-in windows VPN capability which will have no such feature as split tunneling. So I'm going to give you a solution that works for this instead:

```
1. Edit your VPN connection settings
```

[image]

```
2. Go to the tab Networking
3. Double Click the TCP/IP v4 item
```

[image]

```
4. Click on the button [Advanced...]
```

[image]

```
5. Uncheck [_] use default gateway on remote network
```

[image]

All traffic (including internet traffic) will now be local except for ip specific traffic.

Comment: I have looked through all the settings on the network card as well as the settings for the VPN but I don't see any option "use default gateway..." anywhere.

Comment: @Devolus I added images to the solution to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your VPN is configured to route ALL traffic over the VPN. This includes all your local network traffic as well (except traffic to the default gateway). You should be able to verify this with the `netstat -rn` command in `cmd.exe`.

To change this behaviour, check your VPN client for a feature called 'split tunneling'. Depending on the product, this might be a user-configurable setting, or just for the administrator. You could also Google the VPN product name with split tunneling.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off taking over your entire connection by going to the properties of the VPN, Networking tab, "Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)" properties, Advanced, untick "Use default gateway on remote network".